# Post in Google+ Domains using web tools

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-domain-api

if anyone knows how I can publish something on google + using **PHP**.
I used Google plus Domains API, but it only give access for read.
If I can do it by g suite please tell me how can I do it.

//add code

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
    $client>setAccessToken(unserialize(get_option('google_access_token')));
    $plus = new \Google_Service_Plus($client);
    $plusDomain = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains($client);
    $activity = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains_Activity();
    $obj = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains_ActivityObject();
    try{

        $userId = $plusDomain->people->get('me')->id;



        $obj->setContent("Test text");
        $obj->setActor($userId);

        $activity->setObject($obj);
        $activity->setActor($userId);

        $activity->setTitle("title");


        $plusDomain->insert($userId,$activity);
```

on line setActor my code not continue
http://i.prntscr.com/yM7xybRnTzy8H97jY7DKCg.png

Comment: Ever asked google about this?

Comment: normally if you had tried to code..we would be of help to fix your code.... but since you haven't even tried... we are of no help to you.. look google ... you might many links ... even developer. google .com can help you.. please check over there before posting any query here. :)

Comment: Yes sure , first I asked google but until not answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different APIs, and your question appears to be combining them.   The Google+ api used grants read only access to the Google+ social media website.  The Google plus domains api which gives you access to post to your Google plus domains account (gsuite).

You say you want to post to Google+ assuming that you mean the social media website then the answer is you cant the Google+ api as already stated is read only.

Your code appears to be using the Google+ domains api which you need to make sure that the user you are authenticating with has access to a google+ domains account if its not working have the Admin check the users access to the domain account

Comment: Thank you for answer DalmTo,
Now I have all access to google domain, but when I want post something, it no do. I read many comment and on here and on other system but not find good result !

Comment: Check with the domain admin you may have to set it up https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation  Unfortunately i dont have access to a domains account so i cant help you test it.